# WMD Markdown Editor with a custom preview

Tags: javascript, markdown, preview, wmd

I'd like to use WMD with [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/). I don't need any new buttons in the editor, but I need the live preview to reflect the use of the extra markdown features, most notably [tables](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table).

Is there a WMD configuration option to use a preview generated server-side? Similar to the `previewParserPath` value for [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/documentation/)? If not, what are my other options?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a cross-language markdown implementation here: http://code.google.com/p/mdown/

It's a derivative of showdown, which is the Markdown implementation used in wmd.

It's currently 99% working in PHP and javascript, with one small non-critical bug in the javascript version.

I intend to add the features from PHP Markdown Extra ASAP, so they'll be available in both the javascript and PHP versions. In fact this was the whole reason I started this project...

So, it's not really an answer I guess, but if you're patient this should be ready by some time next week. Or, if you want to try adding it yourself, I can give you access to the project and you can take a shot at it.

Comment: But then I'd have to rewrite most of the WMD editor, wouldn't I?

Comment: ... 'cause I already have an implementation; this is just another implementation. Doesn't help me, unless your implementation includes a GUI and a toolbar for editing.

Comment: My implementation should hook up to the WMD editor pretty much seamlessly. Give it a try.

Comment: @no - Ok, now I get it... WMD uses `showdown` and your `mdown` is based on `showdown` and consequently should integrate seamlessly... but the Markdown Extra features aren't available yet, eh?

Comment: @LeguRi - Yeah, that's pretty much it. I thought I'd have more time to work on it, but it's not ready yet. I've got markdown extra mostly ported from php, but there are some integration issues (it wants its parent class, which is a little different than showdown, and the /x regex modifier). It should be ready before too long, though. Keep an eye on this page: http://code.google.com/p/mdown/updates/

Comment: @no - Any progress? I tried your [test page](http://mdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/example/index.html) but was unable to use [Markdown Extra tables](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/extra/#table).